# Using MCPKit framework in Cocoa app

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I'm trying to integrate the MCPKit MySQL framework available at http://mysql-cocoa.sourceforge.net/ into my cocoa application. I've added the framework and included the header file but when I try to define my first MCPConnection variable it says "MCPConnection undeclared". Is anyone successfully using MCPKit on leopard ? Or is there another framework that people use to access MySQL ?

Comment: "I've added the framework ..." You might want to expand on this as it's likely the problem. How exactly did you add the framework to your project? Does it appear in the "linked frameworks" group? Is it also part of the target's "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [guide](http://blog.ryanrhee.net/?p=80) on how to get MCPKit up and running on XCode 3.2.x :)
People from Sequel Pro gave me a copy of the MCPKit they used, which is a bit updated from the ones you can find floating around google.

P.S. I couldn't post a link to Sequel Pro because this is my first post. -_-;;

Best,
-R